# Foreach update sql loop don't create loops

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I have some strange problems with this codes:

**The while loopp that contains a form inside**

```
  <?php 
  $sql = "SELECT *  FROM sessions WHERE SES = '$SES' ORDER BY ID DESC";
  $preorders = mysql_query($sql);
  while ($pre = mysql_fetch_array($preorders)) { ?>

   <tr>
     <td class="center">
     <form id="update" action="update" method="post">
     <input type="number" name="QTY[]" value="<?=$pre[QTY]?>" min="1" max="100">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID[]" value="<?=$pre[ID]?>">
    </form></td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

**The submit button**

```
<button type="submit" form="update">Update</button>
```

**Process page**

```
foreach ($_POST['ID'] as $key => $ID) {
$QTY = $_POST['QTY'][$key]; 
mysql_query("UPDATE sessions SET QTY= '$QTY' WHERE ID = '$ID' ");
}
```

**THE ISSUE**

That foreach update only the first item. Mostly, I need to update more than one item. Where is the problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: still doesn't work...

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql-injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Please, take a look at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Is everything ok with the forms? Are they printed on screen exactly as you want them?

Comment: Inspect the page and check if everything is correctly being filled. var_dump variables and check their values. Also, you have a variable called `$book` but you don't use it in your code..

Comment: @dimlucas yes. on the process page the first item values is printed fine.

Comment: @FirstOne you're right. i forgot to remove that variable. helps to generate the price value for other <td>

Comment: @Adrian So only the first item is printed? Or all of them? I mean is there any issue with the first block of code you posted or is it just for reference?

Comment: @dimlucas only the first is printed. i can't figured it out what is the problem. the first block is just for reference.

Comment: Well unless there is some JS you omitted, you actually have multiple forms so hitting you update button is only going to submit one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things going wrong with your code. First you use `[]` in this input's name:

`<input type="number" name="QTY[]" value="<?=$pre[QTY]?>" min="1" max="100">`

and this input as well:

`<input type="hidden" name="ID[]" value="<?=$pre[ID]?>">`

You probably want to place them inside `<?php ... ?>` tags.

Second. You only have one update button but multiple forms. Each form needs its own update button which needs to be included inside each `<form>` element.

Third. You're using the deprecated `mysql` functions. Change to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Fourth. You should use Prepared Statements for your update query or else your code is susceptible to SQL Injection.